# Linq for a hierarchical relationship model with Entity Framework, Filtering nested tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have got the following database model, I need to query the company entity for an specific UserName from the table AspNetUsers. I do not how to filter and drill into the related hierarchical tables using Linq lambda expression with Entity Framework. All my domain classes have their foreign keys and navigation properties required.I would appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understand i given the solution . I hope it may help you.

```
        //Test Data 

        DataTable Companies = new DataTable();
        Companies.Columns.Add("Companyid", typeof(string));
        Companies.Columns.Add("CompanyName", typeof(string));

        DataTable Teams = new DataTable();
        Teams.Columns.Add("Companyid", typeof(string));
        Teams.Columns.Add("TeamID", typeof(string));

        DataTable ApplicationUserTeam = new DataTable();
        ApplicationUserTeam.Columns.Add("TeamID", typeof(string));
        ApplicationUserTeam.Columns.Add("ApplicationUserID", typeof(string));

        DataTable AspnetUsers = new DataTable();
        AspnetUsers.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
        AspnetUsers.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

        Companies.Rows.Add("10", "Infosys");
        Companies.Rows.Add("12", "Tech mahindra");

        Teams.Rows.Add("10", "T18");
        Teams.Rows.Add("12", "T12");

        ApplicationUserTeam.Rows.Add("T10", "120");
        ApplicationUserTeam.Rows.Add("T12", "110");

        AspnetUsers.Rows.Add("110", "king");
        AspnetUsers.Rows.Add("112", "little");


        var id = AspnetUsers.AsEnumerable().Where(s => s.Field<string>("Name").Equals("king")).Select(s => s.Field<string>("ID")).First();
        var Teamid = ApplicationUserTeam.AsEnumerable().Where(s => s.Field<string>("ApplicationUserID").Equals(id)).Select(s => s.Field<string>("TeamID")).First();
        var Companyid = Teams.AsEnumerable().Where(s => s.Field<string>("TeamID").Equals(Teamid)).Select(s => s.Field<string>("Companyid")).First();
        var Company = Companies.AsEnumerable().Where(s => s.Field<string>("Companyid").Equals(Companyid));

        foreach (var item in Company)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item[0] + "  " + item[1]);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution works. However I am waiting to see if i can get the same result with one sole Linq expression. Maybe using Any() method for the collections. I am not sure about it.

Comment: I hope this one is u looking for

Comment: var v = Companies.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(c => c.Field<string>("Companyid") == Teams.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(t => t.Field<string>("TeamID") == ApplicationUserTeam.AsEnumerable()
                     .Where(a => a.Field<string>("ApplicationUserID") == AspnetUsers.AsEnumerable().
                         Where(u => u.Field<string>("Name") == "king").Select(u => u.Field<string>("ID")).First())
                         .Select(a => a.Field<string>("TeamID")).First())
                         .Select(t => t.Field<string>("Companyid")).First());

Answer (score 0):

without knowing your database context etc it would be something like

```
db.Comapnies.Include(c => c.Teams
                           .Select(t => t.ApplicationUserTeam
                                         .Select(aut => aut.AspNetUsers)));
```

Comment: I do not want to include related entities,  I need to return only Company entity. Include will always bring in all related entities. I was thinking to use Any() for the related entities but I am not sure how to build the Linq expression.